# How to query json object array in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to query the url in a field value like this:

```json
["{\"Success\":null,\"Fail\":null,\"Url\":\"http://www.baidu.com\",\"Method\":\"Post\",\"Data\":\"\",\"ContentType\":\"application/json\",\"Timeout\":120000,\"DelayFromMinutes\":15,\"Cron\":\"33 10 3/6 * * ?\",\"JobName\":\"Test@asyncOrder\",\"QueueName\":\"recurring\",\"AgentClass\":null,\"SendSuccess\":false,\"SendFail\":true,\"Mail\":\"xxxxxx@qq.com\",\"EnableRetry\":true,\"RetryDelaysInSeconds\":null,\"RetryTimes\":0,\"BasicUserName\":null,\"BasicPassword\":null,\"Headers\":{},\"CallbackEL\":null,\"TimeZone\":null,\"DingTalk\":null}","\"Test@asyncOrder\"","\"recurring\"","true",null]
```

What should I do？

Comment: Why tag 2005 (which has been completely unsupported for ~7 years) if you are using 2016? As for the problem, have you looked at SQL Server's in built JSON features? Though, I'm not actually sure if that is valid JSON; if it isn't then either you should fix that or you would likely be better off using a language that is much better at string manipulation, as T-SQL is terrible at it.

Comment: You can do this, but it's NEVER going to be efficient. If you need to look inside JSON, you almost always should instead update the schema to pull out those fields at INSERT/UPDATE time. This will be -- without any exaggeration -- 100x or more faster.

Comment: `json_value(json_value(column, '$[0]'), '$.Url')`

Answer (score -1):

I think I need some further clarification on this.

- Are you trying to pass the entire json object into the query as an array of key-value pairs?
- If so, do you want that pass to be all one string--commas, colons and everything?
- OR are you passing the value for each key into its own parameter in the query?

In any event, I would likely want to utilize STRING_ESCAPE:

```
... WHERE Thing = STRING_ESCAPE(@Thing, 'json') ...
```